Kubectl get pod names without the extra numbers K8s assigns it
Is there a way to get just back the pod names without all the alphanumeric numbers K8s assigns it?
For example:
Pod name = app.kubernetes.io/name: capture-kafdrop

When running kubectl get-pods I get back the name plus all the alphanumeric characters k8s assigns to it
get pods --all-namespaces | grep -i capture-kafdrop

kafka                   capture-kafdrop-c979cdb96-45d99                                 1/1     Running                           0                  22d

My goal is to just get back all the pods name without the all the alphanumeric characters k8s assigns to it to get a distinct list of all the pods running in all the namespaces.
Thank you

yeah, but it is exactly those characters that make the pod distict, it is the only part that differs, if you have multiple replicas for a deployment. So your use case only works when you have a single replica, and that is not recommended.

@Jonas I understand that but I'm just wanting the pod names minus the alphanumeric characters at the moment. Do you know a way?

How about this:
kubectl get pods -A | grep -i capture-kafdrop|sed -E 's/ (.*)-[a-f0-9]{10}-[a-z0-9]{5} / \1 /'

test result:
$ kubectl get pods -A | grep -i my-backend-api-dev|sed -E 's/ (.*)-[a-f0-9]{10}-[a-z0-9]{5} / \1 /'

development      my-backend-api-dev                 1/1     Running   0                18h


If you just need the app name you can run
kubectl get deployments --all-namespaces | grep -i capture-kafdrop

Instead of get pods.
Basically pod_name is deployment_name+some_string
Edit:
Another way if all the pods have the label like in your example
kubectl get pods -o go-template='{{ range .items }}{{ index .metadata.labels "app.kubernetes.io/name" }}{{ "\n" }}{{end}}'

Output:
  service-a
  service-b
  <no value>
  <no value> # for the pods without this lable
  service-d


That's a good point. Deployment are just the pod names

Deployments is insufficient. There are other Kubernetes Resources that manage workloads that programs Pods.

@DazWilkin right like statefulset and jobs but daemonset and jobs but assuming the need is for the applications and not system resource, most use cases are deployments and based on the example in the question I'm assuming deployments will do.
